# How do I pass constant parameters through an optimization function that calls another function in R?

Tags: r, function, optimization, parameter-passing

I am trying to minimize a function that is conceptually similar to this:

```
minim<-function(a,b,state){
if(state=="TRUE"){out<-2*a^2+b}else{out<-2*a^3-b}
return(out) }
```

And I am calling GenSA like this (I wish to optimize on `a` and `b` only and not optimize `state`):

```
upper_limits<-c(10,10)
lower_limits<-c(-10,-10)
params<-c(1,1)

minim<-function(a,b,state){
  if(state=="TRUE"){out<-2*a^2+b}else{out<-2*a^3-b}
  return(out)
  }

minim_state_TRUE_fit<-GenSA(par=params,function(params) minim(params[1],params[2]), 
                      lower=lower_limits, upper=upper_limits, 
                      control=list(max.time=100),state="TRUE")
```

And the error I get is:

```
Error in fn(par, ...) : unused argument (state = "TRUE")
```

`GenSA` is supposed to be able to accept additional arguments that it will pass to the function being called. It appears that `state="TRUE"` is not being passed to `minim` for some reason.  Am I coding this incorrectly?  I have not been able to find an example of `GenSA` use where an additional argument is used to check my R grammar.

Comment: Do note that if the call had been constructed properly that setting state to "TRUE" would have meant that it should have failed the test for `stat=="True"`

Comment: Ah, good point.  I've fixed that error in my example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are optimizing the function `function(params) minim(params[1],params[2])`. This function does not contain the argument `state`. You can fix this like this:

```
minim <- function(a, b, state) {
  if (state) {
    out <- 2 * a^2 + b
  } else {
    out<-2 * a^3 - b
  }
  return(out)
}

fn = function(params, state) minim(params[1],params[2], state)

minim_state_TRUE_fit<-GenSA(par=params,fn = fn, 
                            lower=lower_limits, upper=upper_limits, 
                            control=list(max.time=100), state = TRUE)
```

Also note that I changed `state = "TRUE"` to `state = TRUE`. If you're using it for a logical test it's better to change it into a logical if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass named arguments in to a function you need to provide formal arguments to accept them, so put in "dots" in for the `fn` argument definition and the `minim` call:

```
minim_state_TRUE_fit<-GenSA(par=params,fn=function(params, ...) {     
                                                minim(params[1],params[2], ...) }, 
                            lower=lower_limits, upper=upper_limits, 
                            control=list(max.time=100), state="TRUE")
```